# Save Jaccard Similarity in a CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have built the following code to analyze the Jaccard Similarity:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=[0]
                    ,names=['Question'], 
                       encoding='utf-8')

out = []
for i in df['Question']:
       str1 = i
       for q in df['Question']:
             str2 = q
             a = set(str1.split()) 
             b = set(str2.split())
             c = a.intersection(b)
             out.append({'Question': q,
                'Result': (float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c)))})


new_df = pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['Question','Result'])
new_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

The Output file is like this:

```
Question          Result
The sky is blue    1.0
The ocean is blue  0.6
The sky is blue    0.6
The ocean is blue  1.0
```

which it does come back with the result, now, I would like to change the CSV output to show the results like this:

```
Question          The sky is blue The ocean is blue
The sky is blue    1.0             0.6
The ocean is blue  0.6             1.0
```

I was trying to change the code and use writerows but I guess I'm missing something, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `defaultdict` with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from collections import defaultdict

out1 = defaultdict(dict)
for i in df['Question']:
       str1 = i
       for q in df['Question']:
             str2 = q
             a = set(str1.split()) 
             b = set(str2.split())
             c = a.intersection(b)
             out1[i][q] = (float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c)))
print (out1)

df = pd.DataFrame(out1)
print (df)
                   The sky is blue  The ocean is blue
The ocean is blue              0.6                1.0
The sky is blue                1.0                0.6
```

Original solution with [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
out = []
for i in df['Question']:
       str1 = i
       for q in df['Question']:
             str2 = q
             a = set(str1.split()) 
             b = set(str2.split())
             c = a.intersection(b)
             out.append({'Question1': q, 'Question2': i,
                'Result': (float(len(c)) / (len(a) + len(b) - len(c)))})

df = pd.DataFrame(out).pivot('Question1', 'Question2', 'Result')
print (df)
Question2          The ocean is blue  The sky is blue
Question1                                            
The ocean is blue                1.0              0.6
The sky is blue                  0.6              1.0
```

Comment: @jezreal seems I will have to thank you during my graduation... really appreciate thanks a lot.